# Sound not playing on image swipe in veiwpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am having trouble here as I am trying to play a sound while the user performs an image swipe: no sound is being played.

I am getting anerror when attaching `OnPageChangeListener` to my `ViewPager`. Also, `OnPageListener` is not used.

Code related to the error:

```
package com.android.viewpager;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static MediaPlayer mp = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mOnPageListener);
    }

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private int[] mImages = new int[] {R.drawable.no1,R.drawable.no2,R.drawable.no3,R.drawable.no4,R.drawable.no5,R.drawable.no6,R.drawable.no7,R.drawable.no8,R.drawable.no9,};


        private int[] mAudio= new int[]{R.raw.one,R.raw.two,R.raw.three,R.raw.four,R.raw.five,R.raw.six,R.raw.seven,R.raw.eight,R.raw.eight,R.raw.nine};
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
        return mImages.length;
          }
        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
           return view == ((ImageView) object);
              }
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
             Context context = MainActivity.this;
           ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
           int padding =context.getResources().  
                   getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin);
           imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
           imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
           imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
           ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0); 
           return imageView;
            }

        public OnPageChangeListener mOnPageListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                //for Sound 
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.release();
                }
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, mAudio[position]);
                mp.start();

            }
            @Override public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}
            @Override public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}

        };


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
          ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
    }
    }
```

I am really stuck badly here. Please tell me where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what your error is, but if you say that it's "by attaching OnPageChangeListener to my viewPager", I will tell you to do that :

Maybe try to get your `OnPageChangeListener mOnPageListener` out of your `ImagePagerAdapter`, put it directly in your `Activity`.

Or set the `OnPageChangeListener` to the adapter :

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(adapter);
```

and make your `Adapter` implement `onPageChangedListener`.

Hope it will help

Comment: Yes & if i am not using OnPageChangeListener for sound then sound is playing fine but it not matches with the image.

Comment: Have you tried my recommendation ? Try to put a log in the onPageSelected method to see if it's called.

Comment: I tried but still it is not working. Is it any alternate solution for this problem?

Comment: Are you getting into the onPageSelected at least ?

Comment: you tell me is there any error in my code?? Before the modification i had tried this code in which sound was playing fine but not match with my images. see this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106175/viewpager-sound-not-synchronised-with-image/21106401?noredirect=1#comment31755188_21106401)

Comment: I'm trying to tell you to put a Log into your method onPageSelected to be sure that it's getting call ...

Comment: You should probably start by doing some tutorials first. I mean, to Log something, on any language, is a pretty basic and essential stuff.